# Drupal Module Development im using hook_form, How do I use Javascript

Tags: drupal, module, hook-form

I'm creating my first module in Drupal. I have created a `.module` file with the following function, `hook_menu`:

```
    $items['admin/config/module'] = 
    array(
        'title' => 'Module',
        'description' => 'module Management',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('module_form'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer module for other applications'),
        'weight' => 9999,
        'file' => 'module.admin.inc',
    );
return $items;
```

JavaScript works in this `.module` file

This code links to another file `module.admin.inc` where my form is rendered, the form is rendered correctly. However when I want to display some data using AJAX I can't.

It seams `drupal_add_js('path')` does not work.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `#attached` property on form to add `css` or `js` to form

To add css,

```
$form['#attached']['css'] = array(
drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.css',
);
```

To add js,

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.js',
);
```

Comment: Hi Shrish that worked nicely, However I'm very new to this. What do I need to know so I can render the javascript output onto the form. Cheers